# Can i change default color scheme in classic theme windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, themes

Can i change this cofee color (in classic theme) to my own?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "coffee color"? The classic theme consists of black/white/blue and grey. What part of the window interface are you referring to?

Comment: all colors around start button, around OK, Cancel and so on.. not white color, but other. this http://i.imgur.com/6wGrpOB.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, it is the color of "3D objects":

[image]